# Adding a dividing line in between options in a ComboBox in EXTJS3

Tags: combobox, extjs3

I am trying to add a line between options in my combo box in extjs 3.4.  I can get the line added but not get it to populate with my data from my remote location. (It populates if I remove the modified tpl options).

Here is my code.  I just need to add a line in between the 'group' fields so say I have 3 different fields with various lengths I need them to be separated.

I just started learning about templates and the api and googling hasn't helped much yet so at the point of asking.  Thanks for any guidance people can provide.

Also some of this code is trying to use the api or other forums with no luck.

```js
var recipientStore = new Ext.data.Store ({
        autoload: false,
        url: '../../../messaging/inc/action.php?list=to_options',
        reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader ({
            root: 'to_options',
            id: 'id',
            fields: ['id', 'name', 'group']
        })
    });

    var setRecipient = new Ext.form.ComboBox ({
        fieldLabel: 'To',
        store: recipientStore,
        mode: 'local',
        valueField: 'id',
        displayField: 'name',
        editable: false,
        width: 150,
        triggerAction: 'all',
        value: 'group',
        tpl: '<tpl for = "."><div ext:gtip="{value}" class="x-combo-list-item">{value}</div><tpl if = "xindex == 2"><hr /></tpl></tpl>'
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

Taking notes from [user1637759's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12481276/1449525), I came up with the following:

```js
Ext.define('common.field.GroupingComboBox', {

    extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
    alias: 'widget.common.field.GroupingComboBox',

    constructor: function (args) {
        var me = this,
            groupField = args.groupField || "group",
            groupDisplayField = args.groupDisplayField || groupField,
            displayField = args.displayField || "name";

        args.tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
            '<tpl for=".">',
            '<tpl if="this.' + groupField + ' != values.' + groupField + '">',
            '<tpl exec="this.' + groupField + ' = values.' + groupField + '"></tpl>',
            '<div class="x-panel-header-default x-panel-header-text-container x-panel-header-text x-panel-header-text-default" title="{' + groupDisplayField + '}">{' + groupDisplayField + '}</div>',
            '</tpl>',
            '<div class="x-boundlist-item">{' + displayField + '}</div>',
            '</tpl>'
        );

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

which roughly looks like this

[image: ExtJS GroupingComboBox]

and while that doesn't offer diving lines, per se, the grouping helps set different sections apart, which I believe could be even better.

*Caveat: I'm using ExtJS 4, and I can't say for sure if any parts of my solution would fail in ExtJS 3.*

Answer (score 3):

I got it to work with using the template in the correct way.

Below is the correct code:

```js
var recipientStore = new Ext.data.Store ({
    autoload: false,
    url: '../../../messaging/inc/action.php?list=to_options',
    reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader ({
        root: 'to_options',
        id: 'id',
        fields: ['id', 'name', 'group']
    })
});

var setRecipient = new Ext.form.ComboBox ({
    fieldLabel: 'To',
    store: recipientStore,
    valueField: 'id',
    displayField: 'name',
    editable: false,
    width: 150,
    allowBlank: false,
    triggerAction: 'all',
    tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
        '<tpl for=".">',
        '<tpl if="this.group != values.group">',
        '<tpl exec="this.group = values.group"></tpl>',
        '<hr><h1><span style="color:gray;">{group}</span></h1><hr>',
        '</tpl>',
        '<div class="x-combo-list-item">{name}</div>',
        '</tpl>'
    )
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked about Extjs3 this extension would probably be a better solution: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?45412-Ext.ux.form.GroupComboBox

It was written for Extjs 2 but it works great in Extjs 3 for me after I applied the tweaked discussed in post 15 of the thread.

Note that this does not work in Extjs 4 a discussion for doing this in Extjs 4 is here: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?134344-Grouping-Combo